# bind mount with changed mount options from fstab

Tags: fstab, bind-mount

If you mount a filesystem at `/foo` with the mount option `noexec` and want the `/foo/bar` subtree to use `exec` instead, this can be achieved by

1. bind mounting `/foo/bar` on itself

   ```
   mount --bind /foo/bar /foo/bar
   ```
2. remount it

   ```
   mount -o remount,exec /foo/bar
   ```

My problem is that I am not aware of achieving this with one or more `fstab` entries. The man page mentions `fstab` in the context of `bind` and `remount` (without an example, though) so I assume it is possible.

Comment: Here (Arch Linux), adding the two lines `/foo/bar /foo/bar none bind 0 0` and `/foo/bar /foo/bar none remount,exec 0 0` to `/stc/fstab` seems to have the same effect of the two commands from your question, with the only difference that, when using `fstab`, other mount options (e.g. `nodev`, `nosuid`) are cleared (they need to be explicitly added to the second line). Are you looking for an authoritative explanation of how/why this works?

Comment: @fra-san Did you reboot or call `mount /foo/bar` afterwards? I did not try reboot and on Debian. But not a very recent one. Perhaps it's a version problem. I'll try a newer one. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: after adding `/foo/bar /foo/bar none bind 0 0` and `/foo/bar /foo/bar none remount,bind,exec 0 0` to `fstab`, `mount --all` works, while `mount /foo/bar` only does the bind mount (it stops at the first line matching the mount point, apparently); during a reboot, systemd complains about a duplicate entry in `fstab` and again only performs the bind mount...

Comment: ...It doesn't seem an inherent limitation of `mount`, though: if you `ln -s /foo/bar /foo/baz` and change the second `fstab` line into `/foo/bar /foo/baz none remount,bind,exec 0 0`, then both `mount --all` and `mount /foo/bar && mount /foo/baz` work (giving you the `/foo/bar` subtree mounted with the `exec` option). Rebooting fails, though, with systemd complaining about a non-canonical mount path.